# How to prove practically that something is not a vector field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, vector-fields

I have some intuitive understanding about the definition of a vector field, eg. that a vector field has to be invariant under coordinate rotations. I can also find the following short-hand equation relating the components of the transformed $\pmb{A'}$ to the original vector $\pmb{A}$ as

$$ A_i' = \alpha_{i' k} A_k $$

However I can't seem to understand how to use this definition in practice to show that something is not a vector field.

A particular example that's been bothering me is a naive solution of the differential Gauss's law (written without any constants for simplicity)

$$ \nabla \cdot \pmb{E} = \rho \; ,$$

which might be "technically" solved by building a vector field from the primitive functions of the charge density

$$ E_i = \frac{1}{3}\int \rho \, dx_i \; .$$

It is easy to see that Gauss's law is satisfied if I take the divergence of this field.

I am sure, however, that something is incorrect here, but I can't exactly show what's wrong. My intuition tells me that defining $\pmb{E}$ this way does not produce a vector field in a physical sense. However, if I just take an arbitrary rotation matrix $R$ and multiply the vector field with it, I am doing the matrix multiplication exactly the same way as I would "define" the vector field transformation. Hence it looks like $\pmb{E}$ is a vector field - but then again, everyhing would be a vector field, so there's definitely some flaw in my thinking.

How do I prove, in practice, that this $\pmb{E}$ is not a vector field (if this is indeed the problem)?

Comment: Have you tried putting limits on your integral?  You need to use *some* informationa as to where you are evaluating your electric field. As it stands your expression   is not even a number, never mind a vector field $E_i({\bf r})$.

Comment: I would assume that the elements of the vector field are functions of the coordinates $x_i$, as it would be normal for any electric field. So if you give me a charge density, I just take the primitive function and use it as the elements of the vector field - is that not a well-defined construction?

Comment: "It is easy to see that Gauss's law is satisfied if I take the divergence of this field". Not easy enough for me to see, I'm afraid. The way Gauß' law is usually solved is by integrals over the fields of individual charges ($\vec r/r^3$). As far as "proving" something is a vector field is concerned: you are basically on the right track: everything is related to some quantities being scalars (which we know from experiment). Something else is a vector, if there is a physical law that contracts it with partial derivative to obtain a known scalar (in this case the 3-scalar charge.

Comment: Exercising a reasonable fraction of all possible contractions between derivatives and physical quantities is painful, you have to do it on your own. Be careful, there is also the Levi-Civita symbol, which allows you to build the curl of some quantities. The Levi-Civita is a rank-3 pseudotensor, i.e. basically a determinant, so it changes sign upon space inversion (in non-relativistic physics).

Comment: "So if you give me a charge density, I just take the primitive function and use it as the elements of the vector field ..." Very well: Take $\rho\left(\vec{r}\right) = q \delta\left(\vec{r}\right)$ and you'll quickly find your formula for $E$ to be wrong. We get $E_x\left(\vec{r}\right) = \frac{q}{3} \delta\left(y\right) \delta\left(z\right)$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution is very inexplicit as you provide neither limits on your integral nor specify the integration path. I think you are trying to solve the equation
$$
\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z}= \rho(x,y,y)
$$
by writing
$$
\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}= \rho(x,y,z) - \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z}
$$
and hence
$$
E_x(x,0,0)= \int_0^x\left\{\rho(x,0,0) - \frac{\partial E_y(x,0,0)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial E_z(x,0,0)}{\partial z}\right\}dx.
$$
This does not get you very far because you need to know the  derivatives of the other field components on your chosen integration path, and to find them you already need to know the quantity you are trying to find.